# Place Markers from Name, Address and Post Code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, street-address

In my domain model, for the entities in question, I have the:

- Name of the place (e.g. Waterstones Wakefield)
- The Street Addresses (e.g. 61-62 Bishopgate Walk)
- And the Post Code (e.g. WF1 1YB)

From the above three pieces of information, how can I get a Marker placed on the Map? I am using Google Maps API 3.

Thanks

Comment: A detail blog:http://goo.gl/d8w1J0

Comment: @SureshKamrushi you call it a "detail blog" but it is only a code snippet with no explanation at all on how any of it works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this example:

[HERE THE ORIGINAL](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

HTML

```
      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div>
          <input id="address" type="text" value="Sydney, NSW">
          <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="height:90%;top:30px"></div>
      </body>
```

JS

```
 <script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So the [address] input will take, the name, street and post code all at once separated by commas ?

Comment: try directly https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple It's from gmaps docs.