# How to display a marker on openlayers map using address only

Tags: jquery, openlayers

How to display a marker using address only and not longitude and latitude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place Markers from Name, Address and Post Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703918/place-markers-from-name-address-and-post-code)

Comment: I am using openlayers map and not google map.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers does not support geocoding out of the box.

You could use third party libraries like this one:

https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder

Or geocoding services like [Google's Geocoding service](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)
 or [OGC OpenLS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/ols), which you can see in a working example with an OpenLayers map here:

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/openls.html

Comment: Link dev.openlayers.org/examples/openls.html no longer works, but ol3-geocoder proved useful, thanks!